# open source web application for viewing .ics calendars

Tags: web-applications, calendar, caldav

**I need an open source web application that allows users to view .ics calendars**

I am hosting a calendar with DAViCal, and users can view/edit calendars with their own clients (like Apple iCal or Mozilla Sunbird), but I want a web app that will display the public calendars so people w/o a user account can view the calendar just by visiting a URL.  Requirements:

- **Open source web app**: something I can host right along with DAViCal
- **Human-readable calendar**: i.e. it has a day/week/month view to visualize calendar events

Answer (score 3):

I created an open-source calendar https://github.com/niccokunzmann/open-web-calendar because I could not find one. You are welcome to use this service under the linked hosting site or just host your own instance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [PHP iCalendar](http://phpicalendar.net)?

Answer (score 1):

Hordes ansel can do that too